# Comparing Moving Averages with One from Past Data

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

(I'm writing my first strategy so hopefully this is an easy question) I am trying to show when one Simple Moving Average crosses another, it triggers a buy or sell action, which I have coded right now. However, I want to compare a 10-period MA with a 50-period MA that is from 80 days ago. Therefore, I want to offset/displace/shift that MA over, but I do not know how to use that in comparison with another moving average. There is clearly an offset parameter in the plot function, and that moves the line over on the chart, but the strategy  does not accept that as information to compute when looking at entry and exit points. I need to figure out how to write "the 50-period moving average from 80 days ago compared to the 10-period MA today" indicates an entry point.

I have used the request security function to import the MA data from multiple other symbols, but without having them shifted I can't seem to get the strategy to work. If anyone knows the answer, please help.

Comment: What timeframe are you running this on? Is it the daily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pinescript, you can use [x] to access x bar before.
So'the 50-period moving average from 80 days ago' could be :

```
Sma80DaysAgo = ta.sma(close,50)[80]
```

Then you can compare it to  a 10 period ma like this :

```
if Sma80DaysAgo > ta.sma(close,10)
    /// Do something
```

Comment: I clicked the check, I’m new to this website so I didn’t know that was a thing sorry. If it is not that check on the left then let me know

Comment: @Andrew well done !